Existence of a smooth function with some boundary conditions
Given $\epsilon > 0$, can we find a smooth function $f:[0,\epsilon]\rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying the following conditions?

$f(0)=1$ and $f(\epsilon) =0$.
$f^{(n)}(0+) = f^{(n)}(\epsilon-)=0$, i.e., for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ both the right $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$ at $0$ and left $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$ at $\epsilon$  are zero.
$f$ is strictly positive on $(0,\epsilon)$.
$\int_0^{\epsilon} f(x)\,dx = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

My natural guess was to take $f(x)=\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + e^{\frac{1}{\epsilon - x}}}\right)^\alpha$ and choose $\alpha$ so that all the four conditions get satisfied. However, I am not able to verify the details. Am I correct on this, or do I need some other function? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Your function $f$ with $\alpha = 1$, that is
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{1/x}}{e^{1/x} + e^{1/(\epsilon - x)}}
$$
(with $f(0) = 1$, $f(\epsilon) =0$) has all desired properties. It can be written as
$$
 f(x) = \frac{F(\epsilon-x)}{F(x) + F(\epsilon-x)}
$$
where the function $F:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is defined as
$$
 F(x) = \begin{cases}
 e^{-1/x} & \text{ if } x > 0 \, , \\
0 & \text{ if } x \le  0 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
It is known that $F$ is infinitely differentiable with $F^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all non-negative integers $n$, see for example How to prove that a function is $C^{\infty}$?. This implies properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $f$.
Property $(3)$ is obvious.
For property $(4)$ note the symmetry $f(x) + f(\epsilon - x) = 1$, so that
$$
 2 \int_0^{\epsilon} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^{\epsilon} (f(x) + f(\epsilon - x))\, dx = \epsilon \, .
$$
